# Grid search and XGBClassifier using class weights

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

I am trying to use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) `GridSearchCV` together with [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) `XGBClassifier` wrapper for my unbalanced multi-class classification problem. So far I have used a list of class weights as an input for the `scale_pos_weight` argument, but this does not seem to work as all my predictions are for the majority class. This is probably because in the documentation of the `XGBClassifier` it is mentioned that `scale_pos_weight` can only be used for binary classification problems.

So my question is, how can I input sample/class weights for a multi-class classification task using scikit-learn `GridSearchCV`?

My code is below:

```py
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight

class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(training_targets), 
                                 training_targets[target_label[0]])

random_state = np.random.randint(0, 1000)

parameters =    {
            'max_depth': [3, 4, 5],
            'learning_rate': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
            'n_estimators': [50, 100, 150],
            'gamma': [0, 0.1, 0.2],
            'min_child_weight': [0, 0.5, 1],
            'max_delta_step': [0],
            'subsample': [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1],
            'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.8, 1],
            'colsample_bylevel': [1],
            'reg_alpha': [0, 1e-2, 1, 1e1],
            'reg_lambda': [0, 1e-2, 1, 1e1],
            'base_score': [0.5]
            }

xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight = class_weights, silent = True,
                          random_state = random_state)

clf = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, parameters, scoring = 'f1_micro', n_jobs = -1, cv = 5)

clf.fit(training_features, training_targets.values[:, 0])

model = clf.best_estimator_
```

Answer (score 3):

The `scale_pos_weight` is only for binary classification, so it won't work on multi-label classification tasks.

For your case, it's more advisable to use the `weight` parameter as described here (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html). The argument will be an array which each element represents the weight you assigned for the corresponding data point.

The idea is essentially to manually assign different weights to different classes. There's no standard in how you need to assign weights, it's more up to your decision. The more weight a sample is being assigned, the more it affects the objective function during the training.

However, if you use the scikit learn API format, you cannot specify the weight parameter nor using the DMAtrix format. Thankfully, xgboost has its own cross validation function, which you can find details here: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

Comment: I have used the DMatrix weight parameter before without grid search, but the problem is that the DMatrix is not defined anywhere when using GridSearchCV. The scikit-learn fit function takes training features as array-like and not in DMatrix format.

Comment: @wieus xgb has its own cross validations: https://www.kaggle.com/marcelo06/cross-validation-with-xgboost-python

Comment: Yes, but can it do grid search at the same time? That's the reason I went with scikit-learn in the first place.

Comment: @wieus By looking at the documentation, I don't think that's possible with the core API. I think would suggest doing it by yourself (i.e. a bunch of for loops for different parameter), I have personally done it before.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the compute_sample_weight() function and set weights for each sample by looking at your labels. This will solve your problem in the most elegant way. See below for 3 classes (-1,0,1):

```
sample_weights=compute_sample_weight({-1:4,0:1,1:4},Train_Labels)
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_distributions=params, n_iter=param_comb,return_train_score=True, scoring=score,cv=ps, n_jobs=-1, verbose=3, random_state=1001 ) 
random_search.fit(Train,Train_Labels,sample_weight=sample_weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-class setup we need to pass `sample_weight` parameter with a list of values (weights) matching the count of data-points (for example number of rows in X_train), to `fit()` of `XGBoostClassifier`. Check the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit).

While using `XGBoostClassifier` with scikit-learn `GridSearchCV`, you can pass `sample_weight` directly to the `fit()` of `GridSearchCV`.

> Note: Tried in scikit-learn version **1.1.1**. Not sure from which version onwards this is supported.

For example:

```py
def get_weights(cls):
    class_weights = {
        # class-labels based on your dataset.
        0: 1,
        1: 4,
        2: 1,
    }

    return [class_weights[cl] for cl in cls]


grid = {
    "max_depth": [3, 4, 5, 6],
    "n_estimators": range(20, 70, 10),
    "learning_rate": np.arange(0.25, 0.50, 0.05),
}

xgb_clf = XGBClassifier(random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)
xgb_cvm = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb_clf, param_grid=grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
xgb_cvm.fit(X, y, sample_weight=get_weights(y))
```